# PHP Extension: Get error (Unable to initialize module) built on vs2017

Tags: php, xampp, php-extension

I have a PHP extension built on vs2017.

when I load it on xampp get this error:

```
PHP Startup: myPhpExt: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20190902,TS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20190902,TS,VC15

These options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
```

How do I fix this? the deference is on vc15.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to c file:

```
#define PHP_COMPILER_ID  "VC15"
```

and so I build dll.